# What is the difference between "Bind Variable" and "Bind Variable Field"

Tags: apex, soql

I have read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)  that bind variables can be used in dynamic SOQL (which I am aware of) But on the code:

```
List<sObject> testQuery = Database.query('SELECT id from Account where Name = :a.Name');
```

It says that variable does not exist.

Though I know the workaround to put that in the string with the binding of the variable then pass in the whole string in the query.

Question is when does it became a "Bind Variable Field" and when does it became a "Bind Variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind variable: you have a *local* primitive data type variable and you want to bind its value. I.E.

```java
Integer quantity = 10;
Database.query('SELECT AccountId FROM Asset WHERE Quantity =: quantity');
```

Bind variable **fields**: you have a complex object, like a custom type or a SObject, and you want to bind the value of its property. In this case you must declare a variabile of the correct primitive data type assinging the value you want to bind. I.E.

```java
Account acc = ...;
String industry = acc.Industry;
Database.query('SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE Account.Industry =: industry');
```

Keep in mind that the variable you want to bind must have a local scope.
Not Allowed:

```java
Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name =: SomeClass.SOME_CONSTANT');
```

Allowed:

```java
String name = SomeClass.SOME_CONSTANT;
Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name =: name');
```

Comment: So If I actually have an Account, and I use :account_somefield. That is actually a bind variable field.

If I use string x = account_somefield. and used that string x in the query that is actually a bind variable. Correct?

Comment: @Tachzxc That's right, indeed with `:account.xyz__c` you're trying to bind a field (xyz__c) of a variable (account).